# Proper execution phase for maven-gpg-plugin?

Tags: maven

This is a very silly question, but I'm having trouble configuring the `maven-gpg-plugin` on my POM to work properly. Basically I want it to sign artifacts only when I run `mvn deploy`, as to not ask my password (to decrypt my private key) when I run a `clean install`. It seems reasonable that anyone that download my project on github should be able to run `clean install` even without my private key.

Ok, so I thought of doing this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

But that doesn't work, as the OSS Sonatype will complain the artifacts are **not signed**. If I replace the `deploy` (which should work fine) phase with the `ìnstall` phase, then it signs properly for OSS Sonatype when I run `mvn deploy`, but then it runs even when I run `mvn install` (which I do not wish). What am I missing?

Comment: So you want to sign the deployed artifact but not the installed artifact. Why? This is a bit weird to deploy something that you don't install. Not even sure it'd work actually.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-pgp-signatures-with-maven/

Comment: @Tunaki what I want is to be able to deploy from my computer to maven central with `mvn deploy`, but also let anyone be able to run `mvn clean install` from any computer, even if they don't have my credentials. I see no reason to sign the artifacts when I run an install, only when I run a deploy command.

Comment: Yes, then your best bet is to use a specific profile for that, as shown the article I linked you to.

Comment: @Tunaki thats a good idea :) Then I can run something like `mvn deploy -Pdeploy` and not tamper with everybody else's clean installs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no phase called `pre-deploy` in the [Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) that would be executed before a deployment. It was proposed in [MNG-3869](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3869), but this was closed as  "Won't Fix", and also mentioned in [MNG-4330](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4330).

Currently, this is a job for a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). In the following configuration, the `maven-gpg-plugin` will only be executed when the `deploy` profile is activated, for example on the command line with `mvn clean deploy -Pdeploy`.

This way, when you want to deploy, you can activate this profile. But when users will run a `mvn clean install`, it won't be activated.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>deploy</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>sign-artifacts</id>
              <phase>verify</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```