# Parent Pom Does Not Get Signed on Maven Release

Tags: maven, release, maven-gpg-plugin

I'm currently trying to release a project (https://github.com/DaGeRe/KoPeMe) which is built by maven. The last release worked successfully: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/dagere/kopeme/kopeme-parent/1.3.6/ with commit 4a5ee98abf747e257afc18dccbec1299a23be6f5.

It contains the `maven-gpg-plugin`, the `maven-javadoc-plugin` and the `maven-source-plugin` in the parent pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>sign-artifacts</id>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>sign</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <doclint>none</doclint>
        <quiet>true</quiet>
        <nonavbar>true</nonavbar>
        <notree>true</notree>
        <nocomment>true</nocomment>
        <nohelp>true</nohelp>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-javadocs</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-sources</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Therefore, I'd expect all the `.asc` files to be present (for the `-source.jar`, for the `.jar` and the `pom.xml`).

Unfortunately, in the current version, I always get the following errors when trying to deploy:

```
[INFO] [ERROR]   Rule "signature-staging" failures
[INFO] [ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/de/dagere/kopeme/kopeme-parent/1.3.7/kopeme-parent-1.3.7.pom.asc' does not exist for 'kopeme-parent-1.3.7.pom'.
[INFO] [ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/de/dagere/kopeme/build-tools/1.3.7/build-tools-1.3.7.jar.asc' does not exist for 'build-tools-1.3.7.jar'.
[INFO] [ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/de/dagere/kopeme/build-tools/1.3.7/build-tools-1.3.7-sources.jar.asc' does not exist for 'build-tools-1.3.7-sources.jar'.
[INFO] [ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/de/dagere/kopeme/build-tools/1.3.7/build-tools-1.3.7.pom.asc' does not exist for 'build-tools-1.3.7.pom'.
```

It is understandable that there is not signature for the parent `pom.xml`, since it is just not present:

```
find . -name "*.pom.asc"
./target/checkout/target/nexus-staging/staging/3ba66bd2daf598/de/dagere/kopeme/kopeme-junit4/1.3.7/kopeme-junit4-1.3.7.pom.asc
./target/checkout/target/nexus-staging/staging/3ba66bd2daf598/de/dagere/kopeme/kopeme-junit3/1.3.7/kopeme-junit3-1.3.7.pom.asc
./target/checkout/target/nexus-staging/staging/3ba66bd2daf598/de/dagere/kopeme/kopeme-junit5/1.3.7/kopeme-junit5-1.3.7.pom.asc
./target/checkout/target/nexus-staging/staging/3ba66bd2daf598/de/dagere/kopeme/kopeme-core/1.3.7/kopeme-core-1.3.7.pom.asc
./target/checkout/kopeme-junit4/target/kopeme-junit4-1.3.7.pom.asc
./target/checkout/kopeme-junit3/target/kopeme-junit3-1.3.7.pom.asc
./target/checkout/kopeme-junit5/target/kopeme-junit5-1.3.7.pom.asc
./target/checkout/kopeme-core/target/kopeme-core-1.3.7.pom.asc
./kopeme-junit4/target/kopeme-junit4-1.3.7.pom.asc
./kopeme-junit3/target/kopeme-junit3-1.3.7.pom.asc
./kopeme-junit5/target/kopeme-junit5-1.3.7.pom.asc
./kopeme-core/target/kopeme-core-1.3.7.pom.asc
```

The same happens when I go back to `4a5ee98abf747e257afc18dccbec1299a23be6f5`, which was the last commit where the release worked (and the data are now in maven central). This also happens for older tags, and when only doing `mvn deploy`.

If I redirect the output of the build to a file, it seems the gpg plugin is never executed for the parent pom:

```
cat deploy.txt | grep gpg
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ kopeme-core ---
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ kopeme-junit4 ---
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ kopeme-junit5 ---
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ kopeme-junit3 ---
```

Switching to `mvn clean deploy gpg:sign` creates all the necessary gpg files, but it seems to me like the explicit specification of `gpg:sign` is not a good solution. (And also switching the phase to `verify`, like suggested in [Proper execution phase for maven-gpg-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824032/proper-execution-phase-for-maven-gpg-plugin), did not solve the problem)

Since this worked for the last releases (without `gpg:sign`, and all necessary files are online), but even this last releases commit does not produce a `.pom.asc`, I do not see a way to further debug this issue (and all the behaviour stays the same, regardless whether I use maven 3.8.5, Ubuntus default version, or maven 3.9.2, the wrappers version). Does anybody has a hint how to debug this problem?

Comment: See here as an example using the maven-gpg-plugin: https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to be to add the gpg plugin to the parent poms `build` (instead only `pluginManagement`), like this:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  [...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.13</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <serverId>sonatype-nexus-staging</serverId>
      <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
      <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>

<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    [...]
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>sign-artifacts</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>sign</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <doclint>none</doclint>
        <quiet>true</quiet>
        <nonavbar>true</nonavbar>
        <notree>true</notree>
        <nocomment>true</nocomment>
        <nohelp>true</nohelp>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-javadocs</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>javadoc-no-fork</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-sources</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    [...]
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

It makes sense that this is necessary - I assume I was using an older version of maven before (that was installed on the system), and that an update to maven caused the problem.